# Редактирование StringGrid

Tags: delphi

Короче, в delphi проверяю написанное в stringgrid.cells и если надо, то удаляю символы. Делаю это сразу при вводе текста. При редактировании сначала засовываю текст в переменную, с которой потом работаю, и в конце вставляю вместимое переменной в stringgrig. Проблема в том, что при вдавливании весь текст выделяется и при повторном нажатии заменяется, что не есть гуд. То есть после каждого символа приходится нажимать стрелку вправо, например. Как сделать, чтобы этого не било ? Можно ли как-то инициализировать нажатие той же стрелки вправо автоматически ?

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1SetEditText(Sender: TObject; ACol,
  ARow: Integer; const Value: String);
    var i, d:integer;
  s:string;
begin
s:=stringgrid1.cells[acol,arow];
d:=length(s);
if (acol=2) and (d>0) then begin
if s[d]='.' then   s[d]:=',';
if (ord(s[d])<48) or (ord(s[d])>57) then delete(s,d,1);
 stringgrid1.cells[acol,arow]:=s;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: Код покажите.

Comment: @drakka, надо было отредактировать свой вопрос.

Comment: а как тут Value использовать?
s:=stringgrid1.cells[acol,arow]; //можно использовать значение `Value`. у меня только так получается if(aCol=1)and(aRow=1) then Value:= '00000;1; ';

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его, нажав кнопку "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Укажите ссылку на этот вопрос, если это обеспечивает необходимый контекст.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вам не подойдет, например, такой способ:

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1GetEditMask(Sender: TObject; ACol,
  ARow: Integer; var Value: String);
begin
  if ACol = 2 then
      Value:='!0.00;1;';
end;
```

Что касается вашего способа, ничего толкового придумать не могу, но могу указать вам, что вместо

```
s:=stringgrid1.cells[acol,arow]; //можно использовать значение `Value`.
```

А вместо

```
if (ord(s[d])<48) or (ord(s[d])>57) then
```

вам надо бы использовать

```
if ((ord(s[d])<48) or (ord(s[d])>57)) and (ord(s[d])<>44) then
//так как запятую тоже нужно учитывать
```